# Automatically zoom and positioning given a number of locations on iOS map

Tags: ios, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I am working on an iOS app, and I am trying to achieve that, given a number of locations (Latitude and Longitude), I want to automatically zoom my map and relocate my map view to include all the locations.

The solution I came up with was, given any number of locations, I can use a for loop to find the highest and lowest latitude and longitude. And the centre point should be the central position between the highest/lowest of the lat/lng. And using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance, combine with core location framework (distanceFromLocation), I can calculate the distance between the furthest locations and the centre location, and display that region on map.

My question is, is there any better solutions or frameworks that can handle this? and is there any example I can find which can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the highest and lowest latitude and longitude values you could at least simplify things a little by using `MKCoordinateRegionMake` instead of `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
CLLocationDegrees highestLatitude;
CLLocationDegrees lowestLatitude;
CLLocationDegrees highestLongitude;
CLLocationDegrees lowestLongitude;

// Calculate the above variable values...

// These calculations would have to be more complex if you need to handle the fact that longitude values wrap
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = highestLatitude - lowestLatitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = highestLongitude - lowestLongitude;
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lowestLatitude + (latitudeDelta / 2.0f), lowestLongitude + (longitudeDelta / 2.0f));
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `setRegion` which uses longitudeSpan and latitudeSpan, this is simpler because it avoids the distance calculation.

Calc min and max lat and longitudes. then calc latSpan and longSpan from: max - min, then calc center by using mid point (minLat + latSpan / 2.0, minLon + lonSpan / 2.0)